# How to track long press key events in AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, events, accessibilityservice

I want to listen to **KeyEvent**s inside my AccessibilityService. The `ACTION_DOWN` events are successfully triggered inside the `onKeyEvent` method of the `AccessibilityService` class.

But it is not receiving the **onKeyLongPress** event even if call `startTracking()` on the event. Look at this code:

```
@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        if (isVolumeKey(event.getKeyCode())) {

            event.startTracking();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Started tracking!");

            return true;
        }

    } else if (event.isLongPress()) {

        // This code is not executing

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received a long press event");

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}
```

**UPDATE**: The `onKeyEvent` method is only receiving a single `ACTION_DOWN` but not multiple from the same event. However, the same is possible with `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific listener to detect long press event in Accessibility Service.
However, you can use the Handler with postDelayed() method to achieve this.
You can initialise and start handler in KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN like below.

```
if (mLongPressHandler == null) {
            mLongPressHandler = new Handler();
        }
        mLongPressHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Your code
                mLongPressHandler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_VOLUME_LONG_PRESS);
            }
        }, DELAY_VOLUME_LONG_PRESS);
```

And you can removeCallbacksAndMessages() in KeyEvent.ACTION_UP to remove callbacks from handler.

```
mLongPressHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

I have done this to detect volume up/down hardware keys long press event.

Comment: I achieved the same thing using CountDownTimer. As I mentioned in my question, the key tracking is not working somehow inside AccessibilityService.